# Moving colorbox's captions to top of box?

Tags: jquery, css, colorbox

I'm using colorbox to open modal windows on my project.

There is 5 style to use colorbox. I'm using Example 5 on this url: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example5/

I am trying to move colorbox.js's caption row (title attribute text, background and close icon) to the top of the box - it defaults to the bottom. How can I do it?

## **This is normal view of Colorbox window on Example 5:**

[image: This is normal view of Colorbox window on Example 5]

## **This is what I REALLY WANT:**

[image: This is what I really want]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***You have to do two things:***  The first is easy; you'll have to edit the CSS file (colorbox.css) and change the position rule for the following elements:

```
#cboxTitle, #cboxCurrent, #cboxPrevious, #cboxNext, #cboxClose, #cboxSlideshow
```

so that their absolute positioning is based on the 'top' property not the 'bottom' property. Here is an example, before and after an edit (the before version is commented out):

```
/*#cboxCurrent{position:absolute; bottom:-25px; left:58px; font-weight:bold; color:#7C7C7C;} */
  #cboxCurrent{position:absolute; top: 0; left:58px; font-weight:bold; color:#7C7C7C;}
```

You'll have to experiment to get the proper values for the 'top' property.

The second thing to do may be more difficult. The plugin uses an image 'sprite' (a composite of many images) called **controls.png**.  Looking at it, it does not have the images necessary to do what you want.

If you are competent with an image editor, you could modify this image and add the necessary images, then determine the X-Y co-ordinates necessary to use the new image content according to typical sprite use in CSS.  Don't know if you are up for this.

Ah, but you thought it was a simple change, eh? Best of luck!

Comment: Good answer. Should be able to take the sprite and just rotate it 180 degrees, then update the CSS accordingly.

Comment: I haven't got enough experiance to do this. Can you do it?

Comment: @NuriAkamn You can get the new skin here: (https://rcpt.yousendit.com/1498340855/344a3f8b844f4f9cb425d7f971ebd126)

Comment: Kevin, I don't know how you managed to destroy the image quality of that PNG but you did. Excellent work otherwise. If you're using this you can grab a better quality controls.png here http://i.stack.imgur.com/6YNOc.png

Comment: I relocated the new skin referred to above (@KevinM May 8, 2012) to Github: https://github.com/netaisllc/Colorbox_Skins

Answer (score 5):

Simply copy the below mentioned code in the bottom of your colorbox.css

`#colorbox #cboxClose
    {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    }
    #cboxLoadedContent{
    margin-top:28px;
    margin-bottom:0;
    }`

Comment: You might also want to add this:

`#cboxTitle{position:absolute; top:4px; left:0; text-align:center; width:100%; color:#444;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;}`

Answer (score 1):

Edit colorbox.css
Make following changes

```
1. Replace 
#cboxLoadedContent{margin-bottom:28px;}
with 
#cboxLoadedContent{margin-top:28px;}

2. Replace
#cboxClose{position:absolute; bottom:0;
with
#cboxClose{position:absolute; top:0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an easier way to change the close to an image,
change word "close" to your image in jquery.colorbox.js

current: "image {current} of {total}",
previous: "previous",
next: "next",
close: "", //was "close"
xhrError: "This content failed to load.",
imgError: "This image failed to load.",

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
       $content = $tag(div, "Content").append(
            $title = $tag(div, "Title"),
            $current = $tag(div, "Current"),
            $prev = $('<button type="button"/>').attr({id:prefix+'Previous'}),
            $next = $('<button type="button"/>').attr({id:prefix+'Next'}),
            $slideshow = $('<button type="button"/>').attr({id:prefix+'Slideshow'}),
            $loadingOverlay
        );

        $close = $('<button type="button"/>').attr({id:prefix+'Close'});
```

With

```
$content = $tag(div, "Content").append(
        //$title = $tag(div, "Title"),   // comment this line
        $current = $tag(div, "Current"),
        $prev = $('<button type="button"/>').attr({id:prefix+'Previous'}),
        $next = $('<button type="button"/>').attr({id:prefix+'Next'}),
        $slideshow = $('<button type="button"/>').attr({id:prefix+'Slideshow'}),
        $loadingOverlay
    );

    $close = $('<button type="button"/>').attr({id:prefix+'Close'});
    // add this new code
    $wrap  = $tag(div, "Wrapper").append(
            $title = $tag(div, "Title")
    );
```